# define data.frame as a distance and perform hierarchical clustering in R

Tags: r, distance, hclust

```
ggg <- data.frame(row.names=c("a","b","c","d","e"),var1=c("0","0","0","0","0"),var2=c("1","1","1","1","2"))

ggg_dist <- as.matrix(ggg) %>% as.dist(.)

In as.dist.default(.) : non-square matrix

class(ggg_dist)
[1] "dist"

ggg_dist
Warning message:
In df[row(df) > col(df)] <- x :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

 h_ggg <- hclust(ggg_dist,method="average")

Fehler in hclust(ggg_dist, method = "average") : 
  'D' must have length (N \choose 2).
```

I want to perform hierarchical clustering with `ggg`.
 `ggg_dist` is a distance as confirmed with `class()` made out of `ggg` . I want to do hierarchical clustering with `ggg_dist` but this does not work. It shows above error. How can I solve that.

I tried that [How to convert data.frame into distance matrix for hierarchical clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324940/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-distance-matrix-for-hierarchical-clustering) , but get the same error when I try to call `ggg_dist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `dist`:

```
ggg_dist <- dist(ggg, method = "euclidian")
```

Result:

```
ggg_dist
  a b c d
b 0      
c 0 0    
d 0 0 0  
e 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually ```ggg``` contains the distances I have set. With applying ```dist()``` R computes the distances of the distances

Comment: If `ggg` are the distances already, how did you compute them and why didn't you format them as a distance matrix then? The way you set it up seems more complicated than necessary

Answer (score 0):

`as.dist()` requires a square matrix or data.frame. Your original object `ggg` has 5 rows but just 2 columns.

Something like the following would work.

```r
ggg <- data.frame(row.names = c("a", "b"), 
                  var1 = c("0", "0"), 
                  var2 = c("1", "1"))

ggg_dist <- as.dist(ggg)

h_ggg <- hclust(ggg_dist, method="average")
h_ggg
#> 
#> Call:
#> hclust(d = ggg_dist, method = "average")
#> 
#> Cluster method   : average 
#> Number of objects: 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>